# Sintaxis Object.freeze() con propiedades no enumerables

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

en el codigo presentado no entiendo porque al aplicar el metodo en la propiedad 'e', la sintaxis que funciona correctamente es Object.freeze(noEnum 'e') y al usar Object.freeze(noEnum.e) no surte ningun efecto y la puedo seguir modificando la propiedad. Desde ya gracias por su ayuda como siempre.

```
    var noEnum = {
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c: Object.defineProperty({}, 'd', {
        value:3,
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
    })
};

Object.defineProperty(noEnum, 'e', {
    value: 4,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
});

Object.freeze(noEnum.c);
Object.freeze(noEnum.e);

noEnum.c.d = 333;
console.log(noEnum.c.d); // 111
noEnum.e = 777;
console.log(noEnum.e); // 777

Object.freeze(noEnum, 'e');
noEnum.e = 222;
console.log(noEnum.e); // 777
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `freeze` "congela" las propiedades del objeto, no el objeto en sí mismo, el cual es posible modificarlo. Te dejo con ejemplo con comentario para que lo analices

```js
var noEnum = {};

noEnum.e = { a :1 };

//congelamos las propiedades de 'e'
Object.freeze(noEnum.e);

// Entonces no puedo modifcar 'a', porque es propiedad de 'e'
noEnum.e.a = 100;
console.log(noEnum.e); //a=1

//Pero a 'e' si lo puedo modicar, porque lo que se congela son las propiedades, no el objeto
noEnum.e = {a:3};
console.log(noEnum.e); //a=3

//Para congelar 'e' tengo que aplicar la función al objeto que contiene dicha propiedad
Object.freeze(noEnum);

//volvemos a intentar en modificar 'e' y ya no es posible
noEnum.e = {a:44};
console.log(noEnum.e); //a=3
```

Comment: Ya te entendi estaba encerrado en una tonteria. Al ser 'e' una propiedad directa del objeto 'noEnum', aunque sea no enumerable se congela al aplicar el metodo sobre el objeto principal. En cambio la propiedad 'c' contiene un propiedad anidada 'e', por lo cual hay que aplicar el metodo al objeto que contiene dicha propiedad como dijiste, en este caso 'c'. Muchas gracias

Comment: Exactamente, me alegro haber podido ayudarte. Saludos